# Visual Studio Macros stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

My Visual Studio Macros stopped working, with no errors displayed or logged I could find.

<sub>(I did think it was something I did to my machine.)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft released a Windows Update that fixed a security issue ([MS14-009](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS14-009)) that broke Visual Studio Macros.

The workaround, described in [KB2934830](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2934830), is to add

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <runtime>
  <AllowDComReflection enabled="1"/>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

to your Visual Studio Macros Server `.exe.config`.

Depending upon your Visual Studio version and Windows bitness, the file is:

```
64-bit Windows:
\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\

32-bit Windows:
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\

VS2k5 (SP1):
8.0\VsaEnv\Vsmsvr.exe.config

VS2k8:
9.0\VsaEnv\Vsmsvr.exe.config

VS2010:
9.0\VsaEnv\Vsmsvr10.exe.config
```

You'll need to edit the file as an administrator (or otherwise adjust permissions), and it ought to already contain the `<configuration><runtime>` section.

(Although I gleaned the above from the KB article, my Google searching found this via [this](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/).)